# Set a method on all global object prototypes

Tags: javascript, prototype

I was wondering if it was possible to add a function property to all native object prototypes (that being everything on [this MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)).

For example, I could set this simple function to `Array.prototype`, and it would work fine:

```js
Array.prototype.tap = function (fn) {
  return fn(this);
};

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].tap(console.log)
```

But what if I wanted this function to execute on any prototype? For example:

```js
{ name: 'Jonathan', age: 19 }.tap(console.log); // { name: 'Jonathan', age: 19 }
new Map([['1 + 1', 2], ['2 + 2', 4]]).tap(console.log); // Map(2) {"1 + 1" => 2, "2 + 2" => 4}
'Hello World'.tap(console.log); // Hello World
true.tap(console.log); // true
new Date().tap(console.log); // Tue Oct 06 2020 21:09:33 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
```

Is there any sort of "global prototype" I could assign a function to? Or would I have to manually set it to every native prototype?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it on `Object.prototype`:

```js
Object.prototype.tap = function (fn) {
  return fn(this);
};

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5].tap(console.log)
new Date().tap(console.log);
```

This will allow nearly any object to access the method. The only exception is objects which *don't* inherit from `Object.prototype` (which is rare, and must be done deliberately):

```js
Object.prototype.tap = function (fn) {
  return fn(this);
};

const obj = Object.create(null);
obj.tap(console.log);
```

But this is just for curiosity's sake. Please don't use this in real code.

Comment: That was so obvious, I'm not sure how I overlooked it. Thanks!